# Rotating 3 pages in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is what I've been trying right now, but it keeps rendering the same page after the first switch.

I tried to follow the react lifecycle to figure it out, but it doesn't work as I intended.

I want it to start from RepoPage -> TimerPage -> ClockPage -> RepoPage and so on.

How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

```
const REPO_PAGE = '5_SECONDS';
const COUNTDOWN_PAGE = '15_SECONDS';
const TIME_PAGE = '15_SECONDS';

const RepoComponent = () => (
  <div>REPO</div>
);

const SprintCountComponent = () => (
  <div>TIMER></div>
);

const DateTimeComponent = () => (
  <div>CLOCK</div>
);


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      repoTitles: [],
      userData: [],
      commitData: [],
      recentTwoData: [],
      currentPage: REPO_PAGE,
      imgURL: ""

    };

  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const {currentPage} = this.state;
    const isRepoPage = currentPage === REPO_PAGE;
    const isTimePage = currentPage === TIME_PAGE;

    if (isRepoPage) {
      this._showDateTimePageDelayed();
    } else if (isTimePage) {
      this._showCountDownPageDelayed();
    } else {
      this._showRepoPageDelayed();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._showCountDownPageDelayed();
  };

  _showCountDownPageDelayed = () => setTimeout(() => {this.setState({currentPage: COUNTDOWN_PAGE})}, 5000);

  _showRepoPageDelayed = () => setTimeout(() => {this.setState({currentPage: REPO_PAGE})}, 5000);

  _showDateTimePageDelayed = () => setTimeout(() => {this.setState({currentPage: TIME_PAGE})}, 5000);

  render() {
    const {currentPage} = this.state;
    const isRepoPage = currentPage === REPO_PAGE;
    const isTimePage = currentPage === TIME_PAGE;

    if(isRepoPage) {
      return <RepoComponent/>;
    } else if(isTimePage) {
      return <DateTimeComponent/>;
    } else {
      return <SprintCountComponent/>;  
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not have `return` or `else` so `this._showCountDownPageDelayed()` is always executed.

```
if (isRepoPage) {
  this._showDateTimePageDelayed();
} else if(isTimePage) {
  this._showRepoPageDelayed();
} else {
  this._showCountDownPageDelayed();
}
```

Using `setInterval` might give you a cleaner solution.

**Edit:** Your logic causes it to alternate between RepoPage and TimePage. A quick fix would be:

```
if (isRepoPage) {
  this._showDateTimePageDelayed();
} else if (isTimePage) {
  this._showCountDownPageDelayed();
} else {
  this._showRepoPageDelayed();
}
```

Comment: that kinda fixed it. but it still alternates between only two pages. How can I rotate around three pages?

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it says on the 2nd page forever after the first switch.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/4z6j1rpr69. Can you reproduce it on that site?

Comment: It's weird. My code looks same but it just stops at the Clock Page. I added my current code to EDIT.

Comment: both your `COUNTDOWN_PAGE` and `TIME_PAGE` constants have the same string values of `'15_SECONDS'`. They should be unique. Define a different constant for time if you need it.

Comment: Thanks. You are awesome!